# AWS Glue job runs correct but returns a connection refused error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I am running a test job on AWS. I am reading CSV data from S3 bucket, running a GLUE ETL job on it and storing the same data on Amazon Redshift. GLUE job is just reading the data from S3 and storing in Redshift without any modification.  The job runs fine and I get the desired result in Redshift but it returns an error which I am unable to understand.

Here is the error log:

```
18/11/14 09:17:31 WARN YarnClient: The GET request failed for the URL http://169.254.76.1:8088/ws/v1/cluster/apps/application_1542186720539_0001
com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 169.254.76.1:8088 [/169.254.76.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

It is a WARN rather than error but I want to understand what is causing the WARN. I tried to search for the IP that is indicated in the WARN but I am not able to find the machine with the mentioned IP.

Comment: I don't know what it means, but that warning appears to be coming from the Glue ETL engine and not Redshift. The Glue ETL engine creates temporary processing resources (an EMR cluster) in the background, which is where the warning is being generated. Possibly this is due to a timing/connectivity issue when the EMR cluster is starting up or shutting down.

Comment: All the GLUE ETL jobs I have run to this date have the same **Connection Refused** WARN in the logs. I think I might be missing something in my end but I am not modifying the code automatically generated bu the GUI. I am just mapping the columns from S3 to Redshift.

Comment: I faced the same kind of error but at the time of connecting to postgres RDS. In my case I was using an older version of pg8000, upgrading that resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed these error comming up to me in my AWS Glue Job so I found something that could be helpful from AWS:

```
This WARN message is not so special, and does not mean job failure or any errors directly. I guess there should be other cause.
I would recommend you to enable continuous logging, and check both driver/executor logs to see if there are any suspicious behavior.
If you enable job bookmark, please try disabling it and see how it goes without bookmark.
```

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=927547

I had dissabled bookmarks from the begining. What I check is that my Glue job writing data to S3 and got an exeption per Memory, so what I did is to repartition the data.

`MyDynamicFrame.coalesce(100).write.partitionBy("month").mode("overwrite").parquet("s3://"+bucket+"/"+path+"/out_data")`

so if you have some write opperations, I'll recommend to check how you are writing to S3

Comment: I would recommend putting some try/except statements in the code and print statements in the except blocks with the exception. Put some kind of marker in the log statement like "ERROR***" so you can search on it